# Force a link in Chrome(or other browser) to open in Mobile Safari on IOS6?

Tags: google-chrome, ios6, mobile-safari, passbook

I want my customers to be able to download a passbook file. As of this moment Chrome does not support this format and seems to hang on the download.

Is there a way to force a link in Chrome(or any other browser for that matter) to open in Mobile Safari? Or can I otherwise server my customers the passbook file so it is recognised by IOS6?

Right now I am considering either serving them a page with a link that has to be opened in safari or sending them the coupon by email(hoping they use the native email client, since the 3rd party ones dont seem to support passbook either)

Answer (score 0):

iOS Chrome supports Passbook .pkpass files as of v23.0.1271.91.  Ensure that you are serving with the correct mime type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`.

For earlier versions and other browsers we sniff the user agent and render a pass in the browser.  Try visiting this [example](https://r.pass.is/RMgjTv2uI4Ti) with different browsers and devices.